# Why will my app not move to the next class (intent)?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been trying for a while to get my app to move to its next class, "GameOver.class". Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong? According to my log the OnAnimationEnd method is not even being hit. The class, GameOver does work if I use it as the main class.

```
public class Rocky extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

TextView m_dog, m_spoon, m_ice_cream, m_car, m_giraffe ;
ImageView rocky_pic, dog, spoon,ice_cream, car, giraffe;
Animation animationFadeOut, animationFadeIn,viewObjFades;
int count = 0;
MediaPlayer mp;
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rocky);

    rocky_pic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.rocky_pic);


    Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    rocky_pic.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);

    m_car=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_car);
    m_dog=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_dog);
    m_spoon=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_spoon);
    m_ice_cream=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_ice_cream);
    m_giraffe=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_giraffe);

    dog = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dog);
    spoon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spoon);
    ice_cream = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ice_cream);
    car = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.car);
    giraffe  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.giraffe);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Rocky.this, R.raw.ding); 
    dog.setAlpha(0);
    spoon.setAlpha(0);
    ice_cream.setAlpha(0);
    car.setAlpha(0);
    giraffe.setAlpha(0);

}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);

    text.setText("Text.text.text");

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });



    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


    ice_cream.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ice_cream.setAlpha(200);  
            count ++;
            mp.start();     
            ice_cream.setClickable(false);
            if (count==5){

                fadeout();
            }
        }
    });


    dog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            dog.setAlpha(200);  
            count ++;
            mp.start();     
            dog.setClickable(false);
            if (count==5){

                fadeout();
            }
        }
    });


    giraffe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            giraffe.setAlpha(200);  
            count ++;
            mp.start();     
            giraffe.setClickable(false);
            if (count==5){

                fadeout();
            }
        }
    });

    spoon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            spoon.setAlpha(200);
            count ++;
            mp.start();
            spoon.setClickable(false);
            if (count==5){

                fadeout();
            }
        }
    });     

    car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            car.setAlpha(200);
            count ++;
            mp.start(); 
            car.setClickable(false);
            if (count==5){

                fadeout();
            }
        }
    });


}



public void fadeout(){


    animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
    animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(this);

    viewObjFades= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.trns4view_fadeout);



    car.startAnimation(viewObjFades);
    giraffe.setAnimation(viewObjFades);
    spoon.setAnimation(viewObjFades);
    dog.setAnimation(viewObjFades);
    ice_cream.setAnimation(viewObjFades);


    rocky_pic.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);

    car.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    giraffe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    spoon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    dog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ice_cream.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rocky_pic.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}


@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    mp.release();
    Log.v(TAG, "player released");

    Intent end = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
    Log.v(TAG, "end object created");
    end.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    Log.v(TAG, "no anim");
    end.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Log.v(TAG, "sing t");
    this.startActivity(end);    
    Log.v(TAG, "begin game over");
}




@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.rcky_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){


    if(!dog.isClickable()){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.m_dog);
    }
    if(!spoon.isClickable()){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.m_spoon);  
    }

    if(!ice_cream.isClickable()){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.m_ice_cream);
    }

    if(!car.isClickable()){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.m_car);
    }

    if(!giraffe.isClickable()){
        menu.removeItem(R.id.m_giraffe);
    }

    return true;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

}
```

}

Comment: Is the repeat count of the animation trns4view_fadeout probably set to INFINITE? In that case onAnimationEnd will never get called (see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29))

Comment: filtered for MyActivity tags or not, jack?

Comment: No, Nobu. It's not set to infinite.

Comment: There's nothing coming up in logcat anyway.

Comment: that is- logcat was blank for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting rocky_pic's visibility to Gone as soon as you start the animation on it. Since it's a fadeout animation, shouldn't you simply set the animation to fill_after so that it stays gone when the animation finishes? I think setting it to gone, might stop the animation completely and therefore the animation is effectively cancelled which is why onAnimationEnd never gets called bc you effectively invalidate the view by changing its visibility.

Comment: On the money, lxMd. It's strange - I'm pretty sure I just copied this code from the 4 other classes I had, and they work successfully through each transition to the next. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method call, "next()" and took out "fadeout()". It works now but, I have no idea why. Could someone explain?

```
public void next(){
    mp.release();
    Intent done = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
    done.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    done.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    this.startActivity(done);
}
```